# Why aren't the changes I make to my external css being applied to my html file?

Tags: html, css

I just started learning html and css. I am attempting to make a project. However, when I attempt to link my external css file to my html, the changes aren't applied. I'm confident the files are in the right folder. I can write inline css, and those changes are applied, but when I write external css the changes aren't applied. What am I doing wrong? I attached my code. Any help will be highly be appreciated.

[image]

I tried renaming the folders, moving the folders around but to no avail. I made sure all my changes were saved but the changes still are not being applied.

Comment: In your browser, open the debugging tools and reload the page.  On the network tab, is a request made for the CSS file?  What is the server's response?  Which specific style isn't being applied to which specific element?

Comment: Additionally... Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: If learn.html is in prac2, you don't need prac2 in the href of the stylesheet. And you don't have to worry about removing the space after the class, that will work just fine.

Comment: I second "David" ... include CODE, not _pictures of code_.  I'm not even going to attempt to read that.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from just the screenshot. But as far as I can tell from your folder structure, you can omit the `prac2` in the `href` attribute. So just write `href="learn.css"` if your css file is in the same folder.

I would suggest that you read up on file paths and how it works. This article on MDN explains it pretty well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files